# THREE.JS Mouse interaction with shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, mouse, distance, interaction

I have simple point cloud shader, which renders points as circles on screen.

[image]

vertexShader:

```
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
  uniform sampler2D texture;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
  uniform vec2 resolution;

  attribute vec3 position;
  attribute float radius;
  attribute vec3 color;

  varying vec3 vColor;

  void main() {

    vColor = color;

    vec3 pos = position;
    vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projected;
    gl_PointSize = radius;

  }
```

fraqShader:

```
precision mediump float;

  varying vec3 vColor;
  uniform sampler2D texture;

  uniform float useColor;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
  uniform vec2 resolution;

  void main() {

    float mx = mouse.x / resolution.x;
    float my = mouse.y / resolution.y;

    float d = sqrt((gl_PointCoord.x - mx)*(gl_PointCoord.x - mx) + (gl_PointCoord.y - mx)*(gl_PointCoord.y - mx));

    if (useColor == 1.) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
    } else {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);

    if(d < 0.1) { gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); }

}
```

The question is: Is possible to make a mouse interaction with these circles, I mean if the distance from current mouse position is less than point radius then the color would be different?

I have tried to set mouse.x and mouse.y to event_.clientX and event_.clinetY, then pass it to the shader trying to calculate distance:

```
float mx = mouse.x / resolution.x;
float my = mouse.y / resolution.y;

float d = sqrt((gl_PointCoord.x - mx)*(gl_PointCoord.x - mx) + (gl_PointCoord.y - mx)*(gl_PointCoord.y - mx));
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any solutions?/

Comment: Have you tried running those shaders? There are a few errors that would prevent the fragment shader as you posted it from working at all. It's definitely possible but it's hard to help without the full code you've tried.

Comment: I have tried to exclude unrelated parts of the code.
It's weird, but if(dist < 0.1) ... returns Failed to execute 'uniform2fv' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: Remove mistypes, now everything is validated

Comment: [`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) contains the window coordinates of the fragment. The lower left is (0,0) and the upper right is the height and width of the viewport in pixels.

Comment: Probably it should be `step(mouse_pct, 0.01)`

Answer (score 2):

**[`gl_FragCoord.xy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml)** contains the window coordinates of the fragment. The lower left is (0,0) and the upper right is the width and height of the viewport in pixels.

Probably you have to flip the y coordinate of the mouse coordinates, because at screen coordinates the upper left is (0, 0) and the bottom right is the width and height of the window:

```c
vec2 mc = vec2(mouse.x, u_resolution.y - mouse.y);
float d = length((mc - gl_FragCoord.xy) / u_resolutuon.xy);
```

Comment: That's not a problem, cause I have a mistake on if(dist < 0.1) { gl_FragColor = vec4(1., 1., 1., 1.); } 

 Failed to execute 'uniform2fv' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: It works in ShaderToy (at least if I replace gl_PointCoord with arbitrary vec2)

Comment: @VVK `gl_PointCoord.xy` is the position of the point primitive **inside** aisngle fragment, but `gl_FragCoord.xy` is the coordinate of the fragment in window space. Don't confuse `gl_FragColor` and `gl_FragCoord`

Comment: Doesn't matter for now, cause I couldn't place if statement with float dist, see what return in previous message.

Comment: Have found that recent Three.JS has issues with sending Vector2 values to shader, so neither mouse nor resolution — problematic.

Comment: Is gl_PointCoord a ported gl_Position from vertex shader?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var circularPoint = "data:image/png;base64,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";

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        var N = 2560;
        
        var pallete = ["#FF6138", "#FFFF9D", "#BEEB9F", "#79BD8F", "#00A388"];
        
        var verts = [], colors = [], rad = [], size = [], id = [], enabled = [];
        
        for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            
            verts.push(getXYZ().multiplyScalar(5)); 
            size.push(0.25 + Math.random() * 1.25);
            rad.push(size[size.length - 1] * 1.0E-1 );
            colors.push.apply(colors, randomRGB());
            enabled.push(1);
            
            var indx = new THREE.Color().setHex((i + 1));
            id.push(indx.r, indx.g, indx.b);

        }

        var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(verts);
        geometry.addAttribute("color", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));
        geometry.addAttribute("id", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(id), 3));
        geometry.addAttribute("size", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(size), 1));
        geometry.addAttribute("rad", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(rad), 1));
        geometry.addAttribute("enabled", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(enabled), 1));

        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

            uniforms: {

                texture: {
                    value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(circularPoint)
                },
                ori: {
                    value: new THREE.Vector3()
                },
                dir: {
                    value: new THREE.Vector3()
                },
                scale: {
                    value: window.innerHeight / 2
                }
            },
            vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
            fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
            alphaTest: 0.9


        })

        var last_id = 0;
        
        material.extensions.fragDepth = true;
        material.extensions.drawBuffers = true;

        var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
        scene.add(points);

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var inverseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        var ray = new THREE.Ray();

        pickingScene = new THREE.Scene();
        pickingTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        pickingTexture.texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        pickingScene.add(points.clone());

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

            inverseMatrix.getInverse(points.matrixWorld);
            ray.copy(raycaster.ray).applyMatrix4(inverseMatrix);

            material.uniforms.ori.value = ray.origin;
            material.uniforms.dir.value = ray.direction;
            
            renderer.render(pickingScene, camera, pickingTexture);
            var pixelBuffer = new Uint8Array(4);
            renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(
            pickingTexture, event.clientX, pickingTexture.height - event.clientY,
            1, 1, pixelBuffer);
   
             
            var id = (pixelBuffer[0] << 16) | (pixelBuffer[1] << 8) | (pixelBuffer[2]);

            if(id < N){
                
                last_id = id;
                console.log("highlighted node: " + id);
                
                for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){ if(i != (id)) { enabled[i] = 0.0; } }
                points.geometry.attributes.enabled.needsUpdate = true;
            
                
            }else if(id != last_id){
                
                for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){  enabled[i] = 1.0; }
                points.geometry.attributes.enabled.needsUpdate = true;
 
            }
            
        }

        renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => { renderer.render(scene, camera) });
        
        function getXYZ(){
            
            var n = 1E1;
            var rho = Math.random();
            var theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            var phi = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            var x = rho * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
            var y = rho * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
            var z = rho * Math.cos(theta);

            return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
            
        }
        
        function randomRGB() {

            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
            var hex = pallete[i];
            
            var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
            return result ? [

            parseInt(result[1], 16) / 255,
            parseInt(result[2], 16) / 255,
            parseInt(result[3], 16) / 255

            ] : null;

        }
```

```css
body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.98.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.98.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>


<script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertexShader'>

    uniform vec3 ori;
    uniform vec3 dir;
    attribute float rad;
    attribute float size;
    attribute vec3 color;
    uniform float scale;
    attribute float enabled;
    attribute vec3 id;
    
    varying vec3 vColor;
    
    vec3 closestPointToPoint() {
    
      vec3 target = position - ori;
      float distance = dot(target, dir);
      return dir * distance + ori;
      
    }
    
    void main() {
    
        vColor = color;
        
        if (length(position - closestPointToPoint()) < rad) if(enabled == 1.) { vColor = id; }
        
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_PointSize = size * ( scale / -mvPosition.z );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        
    }


</script>

<script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragmentShader'>

    varying vec3 vColor;
    uniform sampler2D texture;
    
    void main() { 
    
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);
        gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);
        if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.1) discard;

    }


</script>
```

That's the result I was looking for, but any tweaks are welcome.
Thanks to [prisoner849](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224917/prisoner849), it's mainly his code.